# How to set Cursor to input value while countdown time is running?

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

I used two Threads run at the same time, one thread is used to display the `timeleft`(countdown from 3s to 0s) and the another one is used to get the input from user and check the input.

**Problem here is:** how to set the `cursor` to stay at one place for user input value while `Timeleft` is still displayed every second in `Console window`. (everytime display `Timeleft` the cursor moves to another place and i cannot input value).

```
Random rd = new Random();
        int totalscore = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            int num1 = rd.Next(50);
            int num2 = rd.Next(50);
            int sum = num1 + num2;
            int input;

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0);
            Console.Write("Question {0}", i);

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0,1);
            Console.Write("{0} + {1}", num1, num2);

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
            Console.Write("Total Score : {0}", totalscore);

            Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int t = 3; t > 0; t--)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.Write("timeleft : {0}", t);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            });
            t1.Start();

            Thread t2 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 1);
                    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (input == sum)
                    {
                        totalscore += 10;
                        t1.Abort();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        t1.Abort();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
            t2.Start();

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
            Console.WriteLine("Total score : {0}", totalscore);

            while (true)
            {
                if (t1.IsAlive == false)
                {
                    t2.Abort();
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: You need to reset the cursor to where you came from in `t1`.

Comment: You mean, after " Console.Write("timeleft : {0}", t);  " add   " Console.SetCursorPosition(10,1); " right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I suggest, but it will not solve your problem if  the input is more than one char. As you use `readline`, the user can enter multiple chars but the cursor will jump to the first char position as soon as `t1` has finished.

Comment: Oh, i see that problem. So how to fix it..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cursor back to `input` position after setting `timeleft`:

```
for (int t = 3; t > 0; t--)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);    //for timer
    Console.Write("timeleft : {0}", t);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 1);   //resetting for total score
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any ways to keep cursor doesn't move anywhere while timeleft is still displayed every second?

Comment: No, in `Console` you'll have to change position of cursor. You're doing exactly as it should be done.